# Code error shows cannot find column specified after where clause

Tags: mysql

this is the code here please suggest a solution for it

```
UPDATE employee 
SET cane_type = 'm', cane_value = 550 , cane_qty  = 52 , price  = 28600 
WHERE cane_type  = 'r' ;
```

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'cane_type' in 'where clause'

Comment: Can you check the table have the column name as `cane_type`?

Answer (score 0):

you query is correct please check that you have the colomn 'cane_type' in the table schema.